# sudo- Command not found error

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, unix, sudo

I have a `.bat` file in which i am connecting to **UNIX environment** . I am passing all the values as parameters to the `.bat` file. When `.bat` executes it successfully connects me to `UNIX` environment.Below is `.bat` file.

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
   set vector[!n!]=%%a
   set /A n+=1
)

SET admPath=%vector[0]%
SET admdatatype=%vector[1]%
SET admeaimethod=%vector[2]%
SET admprefix=%vector[3]%
SET gatewayname=%vector[4]%
SET enterpriseName=%vector[5]%
SET serveruserId=%vector[6]%
SET serverpassword=%vector[7]%
SET iniPath=%vector[8]%
SET userId=%vector[9]%
SET password=%vector[10]%
SET host=%vector[11]%
SET sudoUser=%vector[12]%

echo %admPath%
echo %admdatatype%
echo %admeaimethod%
echo %admprefix%
echo %gatewayname%
echo %enterpriseName%
echo %serveruserId%
echo %serverpassword%
echo %iniPath%
echo %userId%
echo %password%
echo %host%
echo %sudoUser%

echo y | "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink" -ssh %userId%@%host% -pw %password% exit

"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink" -ssh -t %userId%@%host% -pw %password% "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin /opt/siebel/w44gq8sw/exportwithoutFilter.sh %admPath% %admdatatype% %admeaimethod% %admprefix% %gatewayname% %enterpriseName% %serveruserId% %serverpassword% %iniPath% %password% %sudoUser% " > LOV_export_success.txt 2>&1
```

Invoking `.bat` file.

```
LovExportWithoutFilter.bat "ADMpath" "type" "method" "prefix" "Gateway name" "enterprise name" "user" "password" "mypath" "localuser" "localpassword" "Host" "'/usr/bin/su - globepfdev'"
```

I have removed actual values above , except one last parameter that is `SUDO` User.

Now this `.bat` after connection to `UNIX` box executes a **shell script** kept at my local user. You can also see invocation for script in `.bat` file (Done using putty plink).I am passing parameters to that **script** from `.bat` as well.The job of **script** is to connect me to `SUDO` user and execute another script , this local user script is successfully invoked by `.bat` file but connection to `SUDO` user fails. Saying `sudo: /usr/bin/su - globepfdev: command not found`. I have also set `environment path` in `.bat` successfully. Script at local user is below-:

```
#!/bin/bash

admPath=$1
admdatatype=$2
admeaimethod=$3
admprefix=$4
gatewayname=$5
enterpriseName=$6
userId=$7
password=$8
iniPath=$9
serverPassword=${10}
serverSudoUser=${11}

echo "$admPath"
echo "$admdatatype"
echo "$admeaimethod"
echo "$admprefix"
echo "$gatewayname"
echo "$enterpriseName"
echo "$userId"
echo "$password"
echo "$iniPath"
echo "$serverPassword"
echo "$serverSudoUser"

echo "$serverPassword" | sudo -S -l
sudo "$serverSudoUser"  <<EOF
./exportWithoutFilter.sh "$admPath" "$admdatatype" "$admeaimethod" "$admprefix" "$gatewayname" "$enterpriseName" "$userId" "$password" "$iniPath"
EOF
```

In output of `echo` commands i can see all parameters values i need including `SUDO` user parameter value. It print all values correct and i can see **SUDO** value is also present `/usr/bin/su - globepfdev`

Can anyone help me on this ? Why i am getting this error now?

-: **The main point** is if i hard code the values for parameter `"$serverPassword"` and `"$serverSudoUser"` everything is working fine , i am connection to `SUDO` user and performing further task. But when passing it as parameter it is not connecting. Can anyone explain?

Doing Below Works-:

```
echo myPassword | sudo -S -l
sudo /usr/bin/su - globepfdev  <<EOF
./exportLOV.sh "$admPath" "$admdatatype" "$admeaimethod" "$admprefix" "$gatewayname" "$enterpriseName" "$userId" "$password" '$admFilter'
EOF
```

Comment: That's because you're trying to invoke the command `/usr/bin/su - globepfdev` and not the command `/usr/bin/su` with parameters `-` and `globepfdev`. Use `sudo $serverSudoUser <<EOF` (without the quotes) — though this could be problematic in case `$serverSudoUser` contains glob characters.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf you means using "" is causing expansion ? i will try that is there any workaround for glob characters as well ?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks i got your point of why not using "" . I am actually preserving white space , which is not correct  . I will test this soon, and hopefully it will work. Thanks sir.

Comment: You don't have any glob characters here, so if you only use it as shown, things should be fine. To explicitly disable glob expansion, you can use `set -f` (at the top of your script).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks sir , solution worked .